# What is the logic behind Sephiroth's forms?

Tags: final-fantasy

Generally in *Final Fantasy* the appearance of the final bosses have some sort of relevance to one another and/or the plot ie.

*Final Fantasy VIII*

> 1st - Ultimecia Fights
>  2nd - Ultimecia Summons Griever
>  3rd - Ultimecia junctions Griever (similar to what Adel does with Rinoa)
>  4th - Ultimecia begins absorbing all of reality (time, space, existence, stars and planets from across the space/time continuum)

*Final Fantasy XIII*

> 1st - Barthandelus fights the l'Cie to try and force their hand
>  2nd - Menrva enter into Orphan's Pool and gives birth to it, Menrva and Barthandelus are assimilated forming Orphan's protective outer shell
>  3rd - Orphan emerges exposed from the protective outershell

But with *Final Fantasy VII* i'm not quite sure of the connection between the Sephiroth who the party sees floating (after defeating JENOVA:SYNTHESIS), the 2 non-human forms the party fights then the human form Cloud fights in the end.

[image: Sephiroth] =>
[image: Bizarro∙Sephiroth] =>
[image: Safer∙Sephiroth] =>
[image: Sephiroth Again]

Above is the order they appear in. the first one (human, wearing his black coat) is what he looked like before the battle against the 2nd final boss start. the second image is Bizarro∙Sephiroth who is the second final boss. the third image is Safer∙Sephiroth who is the third final boss and the forth image is what Sephiroth looked like in the cinematic battle (where while it shows a battle it's rigged for him to lose with Cloud gaining Omnislash and if he fails to use it and Sephiroth attacks Cloud counters killing him)

My question is how does Sephiroth go from looking human at first to looking like Bizarro and Safer Sephiroth before going back to human? is Bizarro and Safer Sephiroth just more Sephiroth Clones and only the last topless Sephiroth is the real Sephiroth?

Comment: I love this game. Could it be Jenova? I believe the real Sephiroth is the last one that Cloud fight.

Comment: @Vahn maybe but i assumed that Jenova is destroyed (or at least rendered incapacitated given her survival ability) in the JENOVA:SYNTHESIS fight because the next 2 bosses get called ____∙Sephiroth rather than JENOVA:______ like with the previous JENOVA bosses (JENOVA:BIRTH/LIFE/DEATH)

Comment: If Jenova cells can imitate Sephiroth, I don't see why it can't imitate other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can remember (or according to [this Wikia article](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Sephiroth_(Final_Fantasy_VII))), Sephiroth's goal is to become god-like being, gathering a lot of energy.

According to [this article](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Bizarro%E2%88%99Sephiroth), actual name of Bizzaro Sephiroth is "Rebirth Sephiroth", and this is more like intermediate form in his transformation to something more powerful, than he was before. Initial stage of transformation can be seen, when Cloud's party visits Northern Crater for first time:
[image]
Safer Sephiroth is more like final form of his transformation (judging from [this article](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Safer%E2%88%99Sephiroth), it is more correct to call it something like "Seraph Sephiroth"). It is unknown, if it is his desired form, but for sure it is closer to "god-like being", than Bizzaro Sephiroth, as it looks more like majestic angelic being.

As last resort in battle, Sephiroth tries to manipulate Cloud, and final, human form is embodiment of Sephiroth's impact on Cloud's mind, existing only in Cloud's head. And by defeating this image of Sephiroth, Cloud frees himself from this impact.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to lentinant's answer:

It might be likely Seraph Sephiroth is not his desired form, thus only being a "One Winged Angel," indicating that his metamorphosis into a God was incomplete due to Cloud and company.